# pre-populate and update the SQLite db from cordova app (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I am developing a QA type application using apache cordova. And planning to use this application in both iOS and Android. QA forms are HTML files and these files shall be viewed in the Webview of iOS and Android Application. In the app there are many QA forms. Each QA forms may have multiple data entry options like text field, radio button, date picker etc. All these HTML forms have a submit button and when the user taps on the submit button the data will be uploaded to the server using web services.

I will explain my issue here. The HTML files may change after application is deployed. I wanted to reflect the update in the HTML files into the application (iOS and Android). I can do this by keeping all the HTML contents in a SQLite table and access the SQLite from iOS and Android app. My concept is, pre-populate the SQLite database and deploy the application and update the table based on the changes made in the HTML file by using a web service. I know that I cannot keep the SQLite DB in the asset folder of the android application as I cannot be able to update it during runtime. How to p
Do you have any suggestion on how to pre-populate the SQLite DB with the HTML contents and update it during runtime from both iOS and Android Apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can create & edit your SQLlite DB on-demand in realtime from Javascript.  Put the code in any JS, and include the JS on your app page.  Sample code below:  This is a small portion of the code currently used in my IOS & Android Apps.  It does not require Cordova, but runs fine in a Cordova / PhoneGap app.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "1.0", "my DB", 20000000);  // create / Open SQLite Database

db.transaction(function (tx) { 
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CodeDecode (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, RefTable VARCHAR(10), RefVal VARCHAR(50), SortOrder INT)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CodeDecode (RefTable, RefVal, SortOrder) VALUES ("Type","R",2)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CodeDecode (RefTable, RefVal, SortOrder) VALUES ("Type","H",1)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CodeDecode (RefTable, RefVal, SortOrder) VALUES ("Cal","22",1)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO CodeDecode (RefTable, RefVal, SortOrder) VALUES ("Cal","9",2)');
             });
```